# Reactjs is not installing through nodejs command prompt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx

I have installed the nodejs. However, when i run a command to install reactjs , it throws an error.

command prompt:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.17.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.17.0
```

It is important to note that i have installed the node 3 years ago. it was working fine. However, when i recently deleted and then re-intalled it, it is shows these kind of errors. Perhaps, there is some pre-installed file colliding with the flow of the program.

Answer (score 0):

`cra` officially deprecated

you can use `yarn create vite`, or some framework like `next`, `astro`, `remix`, otherwise if you need `pure` react, similar to `vite` you can look on `parcel`, or `webpack`

https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o

Comment: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\r1\firstapp'

Comment: got this error now

Comment: Did you install nodejs from installer? It's prolly missing some dependencies try install packages from this section https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: The error states that you also miss permissions, it's generally bad idea to put your app in `c:/Program Files` normally you do that in `c:/Users/userName/source/repos`